# ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 in Java (runescape API)

Tags: java, utf-8, discord, iso-8859-1

I am trying to make a Discord bot which gets informatie from the Runescape API and returns information about the user. The issue i have is when a username has a space involved.

The runescape api gives a file in ISO-8859-1 and i try to convert it to UTF-8

2 examples from the file: lil Jimmy and lil jessica.
The loop finds a match for jessica, but not for jimmy.

The code for getting and reading the file:

```
    InputStream input = null;
    InputStreamReader inputReader = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

        URL url = new URL("http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-hiscores/members_lite.ws?clanName=uh");
        input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();            
        inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input, "ISO-8859-1");
        reader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        parts[0] = new String(parts[0].getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");

            if (parts[0].equals("lil Jimmy")) {System.out.println("lil Jimmy found");}  
            if (parts[0].equals("lil jessica")) {System.out.println("lil jessica found");}
```

Does anyone know what im doing wrong? Thank you in advance for taking the time to help!

Edit 1: I've added the "ISO-8859-1" to inputReader as told by the answers. Now the next step is to replace the non wrapping white space with regular whit spaces.

Edit 2: The non breaking whitespace can be solved by:

```
       parts[0] = parts[0].replaceAll("\u00a0","aaaaaaaaa");
       parts[0] = parts[0].replaceAll("\u00C2","bbbbbbbbb");
       parts[0] = parts[0].replaceAll("bbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaa", " ");
```

The aaaaaa replaces the nonbreaking space for a regular one, and the aaaaa removes the roman a (Â) it places in front of the whitespace.

Thanks everyone for helping me out!

Comment: If you change the question to include the answers then it makes the answers very confusing and the question conceptually disappear, leaving no future value.

Comment: What does this have to do with UTF-8? You read the text file—now with the correct character encoding—into text datatypes (`line`) and then process. (It's sometimes important to know that Java's text datatypes use the UTF-16 encoding [as do VB4, .NET, JavaScript, …].) Is the text file not actually encoded with ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the downloaded text file:
The whitespace for "lil jessica" is a regular space (U+0020), the one for "lil Jimmy" (and most of the others as well) is a non-breaking space (U+00A0).

If you don't care for breaking or non-breaking, the easiest approach is probably to replace it with a regular white space in your input string. Something like:

```
parts[0] = new String(parts[0].getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
parts[0] = parts[0].replaceAll("\u00a0"," ");
if (parts[0].equals("lil Jimmy")) {System.out.println("lil Jimmy found");}
```

Comment: You were totally right! it was a whitespace and a roman A together. Thanks for your input, you really helped me alot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that you're reading the data correctly, use:

```
inputReader = InputStreamReader(input, "ISO-8859-1");
```

After that, I'm not sure why you're trying to convert to UTF-8, since you're just using the text as `String`s from that point on. A string itself doesn't have an encoding. (Well, in a certain sense a Java string is like UTF-16 in its internal representation, but that's a whole other can of worms you don't need to worry about here.)

Comment: I've added your solution to the code and tried to find Jimmy again. It prints out "lil Jimmy", but it still dont matches in the loop.
For the print, i used System.out.println(parts[0]);

Comment: You'll also need the solution someone else mentioned about replacing non-wrapping spaces with regular spaces -- I hadn't looked that deep into the problem to find that other issue myself.

Answer (score 1):

First you are not providing the charset in your InputStreamReader which cause it to use the default charset instead of the one it should be using, and then you are doing crazy stuff to try and fix it that you shouldn't have to do and that won't work properly.

Also you are not closing the opened stream, you should be using try-with-resources.

It should probably look more like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-hiscores/members_lite.ws?clanName=uh");         
try(BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        if (parts[0].equals("lil Jimmy")) {System.out.println("lil Jimmy found");}  
        if (parts[0].equals("lil jessica")) {System.out.println("lil jessica found");}
    }
}
```